# Can PostSharp compile time weaving introduce problems?

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp

I was reading about **[PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/)**,  And I see that it uses compile-time weaving.

I know that PostSharp is a pretty mature, but is its weaving system safe enough for commercial use ?

Has anyone ever encountered problems, or knows of problems that can be introduced by compile-time IL weaving ?

Comment: It will be interesting to see. I have heard of many people using it, with no known problems. However I have never used it in a commericial situation myself. Though I do love the possibilities AOP brings. Fell in love with it when I finally understood it :)

Comment: +1 this is a very valid and reasonable question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to point you to their customers page http://www.sharpcrafters.com/customers because that says enough to answer your question.

YOU are ultimately responsible for making sure the aspects YOU build are correctly implemented. If you're relying on a "black box" process then you shouldn't be releasing software. Postsharp is a mature product and I have personally released several commercial products to clients with Postsharp enabled features.

Get yourself a copy of ILSpy and make sure you understand how PostSharp works because you can't blame Postsharp weaving if you write bad aspects. Learn Postsharp here http://programmersunlimited.wordpress.com/postsharp-principals/

Comment: That was my general line of thinking. You can introduce problems in anything if you don't do it right.

Comment: It's important to understand what Postsharp does. I highly recommend building a bunch of aspects and reviewing the final assembly using ILSpy. It isn't perfect, but it's very close.

Comment: Of-course I'm responsible for my own code. Was just wondering whether their side of things works properly.

Comment: @Yachai bottom line is, if you run into a situation where Postsharp has done something incorrectly (doubtful), you can bring it up to myself or on the Postsharp forums and you will get a resolution very quickly.